# The installation of Microsoft.RDLCDesigner extension into Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 stuck for several hours and can't continue installation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022, rdlc, windows-forms-designer, c#-11.0

Install Microsoft.RDLCDesigner into Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (Version 17.3.5), the installation process became stuck for several hours and can't continue installation,
using visual studio extension and market place also try to install Microsoft.RDLCDesigner but the installation process can't continue after following the image shown step the installation process is stuck and can't continue.
[Click it to view the issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r3U7.png)
check my connection also but it's fine how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As the log suggested, the `ServiceHub` process is blocking the installation.

Try to kill the Task using `Task Manager` or stop this in `Service.msc` to continue if possible.